# Saving multiple authentication strategies to the same database

Tags: authentication

I need some advice with the logic behind this authentication method.

I'd like my app to have multiple ways to create accounts:

- email/pass
- twitter
- google

I can handle the email and password login myself, but for everything else I'm using Passport.js and oAuth.

Getting the information from Twitter and Google is pretty simple, but I'm having trouble with how to structure my database table so that all these Authentication Strategies can live in the same place.

My unique constraint would be on my `email` column, but what would happen if a user registered with their email and then tried to create an account with Twitter that uses the same email? Should I just fail it at that point?

If a user changes their email on Twitter or Google, how do I identify them once they try to login again?

Obviously all of this is easily fixable if I make the `id` that I get back from both Twitter and Google my unique constraint, but then how do I ensure that the `id` is unique across platforms? Email/Password login would just auto-increment my `id`, so what happens then?

I'm just really confused on how to handle the logic for this, any help would be greatly appreciated.